# How to get class package after obfuscation for use in reflection with Proguard on Android

Tags: android, reflection, proguard, obfuscation

Currently class names are not being obfuscated. I need to find obfuscated package of specific class for use in reflection. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found elegant solution. I store string constant into environment variable with value of needed class package. I can access any needed obfuscated data via static string key of environment variable. Even class name itself was obfuscated I would get always needed data. It is easy to access this data from any module in application since it is in environment variable.

```
static {
    System.setProperty(Const.NEEDED_PACKAGE, NeededClass.class.getPackage()).getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

1. Read the obfuscated package name of the desired class from the <project_module>/build/outputs/mapping.txt and then write it to a file (asset for example) that you can add to the apk as in a new build step and read in your app. If you don't intend to add new classes/packages before (in lexicographical order) the one you wish to access you might even get away with picking the package name from mapping.txt and storing it in a String field somewhere in the app (but this is highly unstable/undesirable).
2. Declare a field containing the reference to the class you wish to access via reflection someplace where it's easy to find (the name and package of the Application subclass are not obfuscated because they are referenced in the manifest so that would be a good candidate) and then you simply use that reference:

   ```
   public class YourApplication extends Application {

       //...
       public static Class<?> yourReflectiveClass = YourReflectiveClass.class;

   }
   ```

And then you access that field and use it as you need:

```
//...

Field[] appFields = YourApplication.class.getDeclaredFields();
Field classField = null;
for (Field f : appFields) {
     if (f.getType().equals(Class.class) {
         classField = f;
         break;
     }
}
if (classField != null) {
    Object classInstance = classField.get(null);
    if (classInstance instanceof Class) {
        Class<?> yourReflectiveClass = (Class) classInstance;
        // yourReflectiveClass.getPackage().getName()
    }
}
```

You might need to alter proguard-rules.pro to keep your new field(s) in the obfuscated variant.
Also note that this kind of defeats (at least partially) the purpose of  obfuscation.

Comment: I think mapping.txt is not an option since it shouldn't be in release version available. Because then meaning of obfuscation is lost.